# Using Design Pattern/MVC in iOS is not working for me

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

suppose my application has two tabs each tab has its own viewcontroller class. 
in first view controller I want to display the Accelerometer data and in the second view controller the Gyro data. So I have created new Class call it IMU in this new class I have few methods such as
take an instance of motion manager and allocate memory for it
second method take an instance of motion manager and three double values(x,y,z), the method suppose to start update the accelerometer and specify the interval and start the acceleration update and finally assign the accelerometer data to the passed double values(x,y,z)
Now, in the first view controller in did load method am calling the method from IMU class and pass it an instance of motion manager and three double values(&x,&y,&z), then I have assigned some labels to these double values which should be displayed on the screen, but unfortunately it doesn't

Here is the Method in IMU class

```
-(void) getAcceleromaterData:(CMMotionManager *) motionManager and:(double *) x and: (double *)y and: (double *)z{
    [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates];
    if (motionManager.accelerometerAvailable) {
        motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01;
        queue = [NSOperationQueue currentQueue];
        [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:queue
                                                 withHandler: ^(CMAccelerometerData *AccelerometerData, NSError *error) {
                                                     CMAcceleration acceleration = AccelerometerData.acceleration;
                                                     *x = acceleration.x;
                                                     *y = acceleration.y;
                                                     *z = acceleration.z;
                                                 }];
    }
}
```

and here is how i call it in the view controller

```
@implementation FirstViewController
double AccX, AccY, AccZ;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imu = [IMU new];
    self.motionManager = [CMMotionManager new];
    [self.imu getAcceleromaterData:self.motionManager and:&AccX and:&AccY and:&AccZ];

// assign values to labels 
    self.accX.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.5f", AccX];
    self.accY.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.5f", AccY];
    self.accZ.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.5f", AccZ];

}
```

hope the is clearer

Comment: show code what you tried one...

Comment: Can you please provide more information and ask a direct question about the problem you are having? I would like to help you, but for me it is a little hard to understand your problem from this question.

Comment: Welcome,Marwan! most of the people will fear to read read your question..try to present it in well manner and post your code so that we can understand your problem.

Comment: -1 for subject and question appear to be mostly unrelated.

Comment: @FaJitendraDeore is this clearer
thanks for help

Comment: @JPetric is this clearer?

Comment: Yes, much clearer. Thanks.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` only gets called once (generally), try setting your UI values in `viewWillAppear` instead, which gets called every time the view "appears".

Comment: @JPetric Thanks for your time and effort, it was helpful, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change method parameters from block. Only local variables declared with __block can be changed from within a block. For example: __block int accX; BUT this only works for local variables.

Consider using delegate method to be called on view controller every time acceleration value changes. Here is example code:

This is IMU.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

@protocol CoreMotionDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)motionDataAvailable:(double)x and:(double)y and:(double)z;

@end

@interface IMU : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, assign) id<CoreMotionDelegate> delegate;

-(void) getAcceleromaterData:(CMMotionManager *)motionManager;
@end
```

IMU.m

```
#import "IMU.h"

@implementation IMU {
    NSOperationQueue *queue;
}

-(void)getAcceleromaterData:(CMMotionManager *)motionManager {
    [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates];
    if (motionManager.accelerometerAvailable) {
        motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01;
        queue = [NSOperationQueue currentQueue];
        [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:queue
                        withHandler: ^(CMAccelerometerData *AccelerometerData, NSError *error) {
                            CMAcceleration acceleration = AccelerometerData.acceleration;
                            [self.delegate motionDataAvailable:acceleration.x and:acceleration.y and:acceleration.z];
                                            }];
    }
}
```

And this is ViewController.h class. The one from which you call IMU methods:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <CoreMotionDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IMU *imu;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CMMotionManager *motionManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *someLabel;

@end
```

and FirstViewController.m class

```
@implementation FirstViewController

-(void)motionDataAvailable:(double)x and:(double)y and:(double)z {
// Here you update view, call other methods and so on...
    self.someLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", x];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imu = [IMU new];
    self.motionManager = [CMMotionManager new];

    // don't forget this or delegate method will never be called
    self.imu.delegate = self;

    // assign values to labels
    [self.imu getAcceleromaterData:self.motionManager];

}
```

This way your ViewController will be notified when acceleration values changes so you can update view accordingly.